# Determine if signal strength is enough to send SMS

Tags: android, sms, signal-strength

I am building an android app that should send sms. When sending SMS I want to check if signal strength is enough to send sms. When not then the app should build a listener that listens for signal strength and send sms as soon as signal is enough.

I think that I only need to check if there is any signal because I believe that only a very low signal is enough to send SMS. Should I use `android.telephony.SignalStrength getGsmSignalStrength()` at begining to check what is the signal strength. If returned value is 0 then I should create a listener `LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS`? Or is there any better way?

Thanks in forward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

> ```
>    int dBmlevel = 0;
>    int asulevel = 0;
>    List<CellInfo> cellInfoList = tm.getAllCellInfo();
>           //Checking if list values are not null
>             if (cellInfoList != null) {
>                 for (final CellInfo info : cellInfoList) {
>                     if (info instanceof CellInfoGsm) {
>                         //GSM Network
>                         CellSignalStrengthGsm cellSignalStrength = ((CellInfoGsm)info).getCellSignalStrength();
>                         dBmlevel = cellSignalStrength.getDbm();
>                         asulevel = cellSignalStrength.getAsuLevel();
>                     }
>                     else if (info instanceof CellInfoCdma) {
>                         //CDMA Network
>                         CellSignalStrengthCdma cellSignalStrength = ((CellInfoCdma)info).getCellSignalStrength();
>                         dBmlevel = cellSignalStrength.getDbm();
>                         asulevel = cellSignalStrength.getAsuLevel();
>                     }
>                     else if (info instanceof CellInfoLte) {
>                         //LTE Network
>                         CellSignalStrengthLte cellSignalStrength = ((CellInfoLte)info).getCellSignalStrength();
>                         dBmlevel = cellSignalStrength.getDbm();
>                         asulevel = cellSignalStrength.getAsuLevel();
>                     }
>                     else if  (info instanceof CellInfoWcdma) {
>                         //WCDMA Network
>                         CellSignalStrengthWcdma cellSignalStrength = ((CellInfoWcdma)info).getCellSignalStrength();
>                         dBmlevel = cellSignalStrength.getDbm();
>                         asulevel = cellSignalStrength.getAsuLevel();
>                     }
>                     else{
>                         //Developed as a Cordova plugin, that's why I'm using callbackContext
>                         callbackContext.error("Unknown type of cell signal.");
>                     }
>                 }
>           }
> ```

To get signal strength (in dBm and asu) for all networks (LTE, GSM, CDMA and WCDMA). And then create an if() to limit signal level. Ex.:

> ```
> if (dBmlevel <= x){ print("You can't sent messages with this current signal");}
> ```

Comment: Ah, and it does not work with Samsung devices. Samsung has a "special way" to do this (I'm trying to find this out too).

Comment: thanks for your answer ... do you know what exact dBmlevel is needed to send sms? Because I dont know what exact value should I asign to x

Comment: I found this one:

-120 is unacceptable
-100 is poor but usable
-80 is acceptable/decent
-60 is good
-40 is excellent

Comment: Basically, your if must retain values from -100 up. Is poor, but usable, so it'll be able to send sms.

Comment: and to make a phone call? -80 is enough?

Comment: I think so, because this is the acceptable level. You can limit from -100 up too, but I don't think this is a good idea, because you can call someone under these levels, but the call would be very, very poor.

Cheers.